# update issue: I just want to update the past or future column to 0 or 1 depending on the date and I can't get it working, can anybody help me?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.DimensionDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE dbo.DimensionDate

    /**********************************************************************************/

    CREATE TABLE    [dbo].[DimensionDate]
        (   [DateKey] INT primary key, 
            [Date] DATETIME,
            [FullDate] CHAR(10),-- Date in dd-MM-yyyy format
            [DayOfMonth] VARCHAR(2), -- Field will hold day number of Month
            [DaySuffix] VARCHAR(4), -- Apply suffix as 1st, 2nd ,3rd etc
            [DayName] VARCHAR(9), -- Contains name of the day, Sunday, Monday 
            [DayOfWeekIRE] CHAR(1),-- First Day Monday=1 and Sunday=7
            [DayOfWeekInMonth] VARCHAR(2), --1st Monday or 2nd Monday in Month
            [DayOfWeekInYear] VARCHAR(2),
            [DayOfQuarter] VARCHAR(3),
            [DayOfYear] VARCHAR(3),
            [WeekOfMonth] VARCHAR(1),-- Week Number of Month 
            [WeekOfQuarter] VARCHAR(2), --Week Number of the Quarter
            [WeekOfYear] VARCHAR(2),--Week Number of the Year
            [Month] VARCHAR(2), --Number of the Month 1 to 12
            [MonthName] VARCHAR(9),--January, February etc
            [MonthOfQuarter] VARCHAR(2),-- Month Number belongs to Quarter
            [Quarter] CHAR(1),
            [QuarterName] VARCHAR(9),--First,Second..
            [Year] CHAR(4),-- Year value of Date stored in Row
            [YearName] CHAR(7), --CY 2012,CY 2013
            [MonthYear] CHAR(10), --Jan-2013,Feb-2013
            [MMYYYY] CHAR(6),
            [FirstDayOfMonth] DATE,
            [LastDayOfMonth] DATE,
            [FirstDayOfQuarter] DATE,
            [LastDayOfQuarter] DATE,
            [FirstDayOfYear] DATE,
            [LastDayOfYear] DATE,
            [IsHolidayIRE] BIT,-- Flag 1=National Holiday, 0-No National Holiday
            [IsWeekday] BIT,-- 0=Week End ,1=Week Day
            [HolidayIRE] VARCHAR(50),--Name of Holiday in US
            [IsHolidayUK] BIT Null,-- Flag 1=National Holiday, 0-No National Holiday
            [HolidayUK] VARCHAR(50) Null, --Name of Holiday in UK
            [PastOrFuture] BIT Null -- Flag  0=Past, 1=Future


        )
    GO

    TRUNCATE Table Dbo.DimensionDate

    /********************************************************************************************/
    --Specify Start Date and End date here
    --Value of Start Date Must be Less than Your End Date 

    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '04/01/2012' --Starting value of Date Range
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '04/01/2015' --End Value of Date Range

    --Temporary Variables To Hold the Values During Processing of Each Date of Year
    DECLARE
        @DayOfWeekInMonth INT,
        @DayOfWeekInYear INT,
        @DayOfQuarter INT,
        @WeekOfMonth INT,
        @CurrentYear INT,
        @CurrentMonth INT,
        @CurrentQuarter INT

    /*Table Data type to store the day of week count for the month and year*/
    DECLARE @DayOfWeek TABLE (DOW INT, MonthCount INT, QuarterCount INT, YearCount INT)

    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (2, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (3, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (4, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (5, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (6, 0, 0, 0)
    INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (7, 0, 0, 0)

    --Extract and assign various parts of Values from Current Date to Variable

    DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = @StartDate
    SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
    SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
    SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
    SET @startDate = GETDATE()

    /********************************************************************************************/
    --Proceed only if Start Date(Current date ) is less than End date you specified above

    WHILE @CurrentDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN

    /*Begin day of week logic*/

     /*Check for Change in Month of the Current date if Month changed then 
      Change variable value*/
IF @CurrentMonth != DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE @DayOfWeek
    SET MonthCount = 0
    SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
END

    /* Check for Change in Quarter of the Current date if Quarter changed then change 
     Variable value*/

IF @CurrentQuarter != DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
BEGIN
    UPDATE @DayOfWeek
    SET QuarterCount = 0
    SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
END

    /* Check for Change in Year of the Current date if Year changed then change 
     Variable value*/


IF @CurrentYear != DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
BEGIN
    UPDATE @DayOfWeek
    SET YearCount = 0
    SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
END

    -- Set values in table data type created above from variables 

UPDATE @DayOfWeek
SET 
    MonthCount = MonthCount + 1,
    QuarterCount = QuarterCount + 1,
    YearCount = YearCount + 1
WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)

SELECT
    @DayOfWeekInMonth = MonthCount,
    @DayOfQuarter = QuarterCount,
    @DayOfWeekInYear = YearCount
FROM @DayOfWeek
WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
```

/*End day of week logic*/

/* Populate Your Dimension Table with values*/

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DimensionDate]
SELECT

    CONVERT (char(8),@CurrentDate,112) as DateKey,
    @CurrentDate AS Date,

    CONVERT (char(10),@CurrentDate,103) as FullDate,
    DATEPART(DD, @CurrentDate) AS DayOfMonth,
    --Apply Suffix values like 1st, 2nd 3rd etc..
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) IN (11,12,13) 
        THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'th'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 1 
        THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'st'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 2 
        THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'nd'
        WHEN RIGHT(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate),1) = 3 
        THEN CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'rd'
        ELSE CAST(DATEPART(DD,@CurrentDate) AS VARCHAR) + 'th' 
        END AS DaySuffix,

    DATENAME(DW, @CurrentDate) AS DayName,


    -- check for day of week as Per US and change it as per UK format 

        CASE DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 7
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 2
        WHEN 4 THEN 3
        WHEN 5 THEN 4
        WHEN 6 THEN 5
        WHEN 7 THEN 6
        END 
        AS DayOfWeekIRE,

    @DayOfWeekInMonth AS DayOfWeekInMonth,
    @DayOfWeekInYear AS DayOfWeekInYear,
    @DayOfQuarter AS DayOfQuarter,
    DATEPART(DY, @CurrentDate) AS DayOfYear,
    DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) + 1 - DATEPART(WW, CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
    DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)) + '/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
    DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate))) AS WeekOfMonth,
    (DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0), 
    @CurrentDate) / 7) + 1 AS WeekOfQuarter,
    DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) AS WeekOfYear,
    DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) AS Month,
    DATENAME(MM, @CurrentDate) AS MonthName,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (1, 4, 7, 10) THEN 1
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (2, 5, 8, 11) THEN 2
        WHEN DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) IN (3, 6, 9, 12) THEN 3
        END AS MonthOfQuarter,
    DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate) AS Quarter,
    CASE DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
        END AS QuarterName,
    DATEPART(YEAR, @CurrentDate) AS Year,
    'CY ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, @CurrentDate)) AS YearName,
    LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @CurrentDate), 3) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
    DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)) AS MonthYear,
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)),2) + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)) AS MMYYYY,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DD, - (DATEPART(DD, 
    @CurrentDate) - 1), @CurrentDate))) AS FirstDayOfMonth,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DD, - (DATEPART(DD, 
    (DATEADD(MM, 1, @CurrentDate)))), DATEADD(MM, 1, 
    @CurrentDate)))) AS LastDayOfMonth,
    DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0) AS FirstDayOfQuarter,
    DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, -1, @CurrentDate), -1) AS LastDayOfQuarter,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, 
    @CurrentDate))) AS FirstDayOfYear,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YY, 
    @CurrentDate))) AS LastDayOfYear,
    NULL AS IsHolidayIRE,
    CASE DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 0
        WHEN 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 1
        WHEN 4 THEN 1
        WHEN 5 THEN 1
        WHEN 6 THEN 1
        WHEN 7 THEN 0
        END AS IsWeekday,
    NULL AS HolidayIRE, Null, Null


    UPDATE 
        DimensionDate
    SET  [PastOrFuture] =
         CASE
            WHEN @StartDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @CurrentDate)

END
SELECT * FROM DimensionDate

Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 99 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I just want to fix the update in at the bottom of this code its not letting me update PastOrFuture Column to 0 or 1 depending on the date

It works perfect if i take out my update and put back in the null.

Comment: How is it not working?  Error, unexpected results, something else?

Comment: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 99
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
It works perfect if i take out my update and put back in the null.

Comment: You need to simplify this code. Can you post the general idea of what you are looking for help with? Can you try removing the parts of the code that you know are not a problem? We need more of a general idea of what is happening and what isn't happening.

Comment: Your `insert` is short 1 column... you have 3 columns after `HolidayIRE`, but your insert only has 2 NULLS after the case for `HolidayIRE`.

Comment: Also, try to format your coder better. It will help you to find this kind of mistakes.

Comment: JiggsJedi, Simple But Effective, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` into `DimensionDate` is short a column.

You have 3 columns after `HolidayIRE`, but your `insert` only has 2 `NULLS` after the case for `HolidayIRE`

Either add a column list to the `insert`, or add another `NULL` to the end of the `insert`.

For that matter, no need to `UPDATE` just tack your case on the end of the `INSERT` and make the case the last column and insert the PastOrFuture on the fly...

```
CASE
  WHEN @StartDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
  ELSE 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your update statement and replace the following code at the and check?

```
....    NULL AS HolidayIRE, Null, Null,
        CASE
                WHEN @StartDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
                ELSE 1
              END
    FROM DimensionDate
```

I think you are trying to update in insert. You can calculate past of future in the select statement itself

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply pastorfuture, count your fields vs the table. you have HolidayIRE, null, null and the table reads HolidayIRE, IsHolidayUK, HolidayUK, PastOrFuture